# Check returns as object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the list of 17 blocks in the PHP page using 'createDivs' class. I'm trying to get the text data on each block in each a time when I press on the enter button of the keyboard to search for the element in the HTML source to see if it has the class called 'blocksList div_1_1', 'blocksList div_2_1' or whaever it is with the integer, so I can display the alert message with the text that says on each block.

```
var current_col = 1;
var current_row = 1;
var totalrowcount = 17;  //is using for how many blocks of rows I have in total 

$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $("div").show();
$(".div_"+current_col+'_'+current_row).addClass( "yellowbg" );
  getBlocks();
});

var current_top_idx = 0;
$(document).keyup(function(event)
{
  var yellowbg = $(".yellowbg");
  var rowwidth = $(".row").css( "width").split("px");

  var displayrowcount = 7;  //is using for to hide other blocks
  var rowheight = 49; //is using for to make measurement from row 1 to row 7 to hide the other blocks
  var totalwidth_current = 0;
  var totalwidth_current1 = 0;

  if(parseInt(current_row)+parseInt(1) <= 8)
  {
    for(var i=1; i<=(parseInt(current_row)+parseInt(1));i++ )
    {
      var yellowbgnextdivwidth = $(".div_"+current_col+'_'+i).css( "width"); 
      var yellowbgnextdivwidthsplit = yellowbgnextdivwidth.split("px");
      totalwidth_current=parseInt(totalwidth_current)+parseInt(yellowbgnextdivwidthsplit[0]);
    }
  }

  if (event.keyCode == 13)
  {  //enter
    alert("enter tested");
    var $row = $('.blocksList div_'+i+'1');
    alert($row);
  }
  else if (event.keyCode == 38) 
  {  //up
    if(current_col > 1 && current_row == 1)
    {
      var currentrowtop = $(".mainWrap div.row:first-child").css( "margin-top");   
      var calcuatedrowtop = -(current_col*rowheight);
      currentrowtop = parseInt(currentrowtop)-rowheight;

      if((currentrowtop - calcuatedrowtop) < rowheight)
      {
     currentrowtop = parseInt(currentrowtop)+rowheight;
     currentrowtop = parseInt(currentrowtop)+rowheight;
     var rowtop = currentrowtop+="px";
     $(".mainWrap div.row:first-child").css( "margin-top", rowtop );            
                              if (current_top_idx > 0) { current_top_idx--; }
      }
      current_col--;
    }
  }
  else if (event.keyCode == 40) 
  {    //down
    if(current_col < totalrowcount && current_row == 1)
    {
                      if (current_col >= current_top_idx + displayrowcount) 
      {
        var currentrowtop = $(".mainWrap div.row:first-child").css( "margin-top");
        currentrowtop = parseInt(currentrowtop)-rowheight;
        var rowtop = currentrowtop+="px";
        $(".mainWrap div.row:first-child").css( "margin-top", rowtop );
                              current_top_idx++;
      }
      current_col++;
    }
  }
  $('div').removeClass( "yellowbg" );
  //alert(".div_"+current_col+'_'+current_row);
  $(".div_"+current_col+'_'+current_row).addClass( "yellowbg" );
});

width = new Array();
imagecontent = new Array();
pgmcontent = new Array();

var checksuminit = 0;
var checksum = 0;

function getBlocks()
{
  var i=0;
  $.ajax({
  url:'database.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:'',
  success: function(result)
  {
    var $doc = $(result);
    i=1;
    $doc.filter('p#blocks').each(function(index) {imagecontent[i] = $(this).html();i++;});
    createDivs(i-1);
    totalrowcount = i-1;

    var j=1;
    $doc.filter('#links').each(function(index) {
    var $link = $(this).html();
    $link1 = $link.replace("&amp;", "&"); 
    if($.trim($link1) !='')
    {
      checksuminit+=j;
      getlinks($link1,j);
    }
    j++;
    });
  }
 });
}

function createDivs(numberOfDivs)
{
  var programsNumber = 1;
  for(var i=1;i<=numberOfDivs;i++)
  {
     $('.mainWrap').append(
     '<div class="row" id="row'+i+'">' +
         '<div id="image'+i+'" class="blocksList div_'+i+'_1"></div>' +
         '<div class="rowSubPgm">' +
             '<div id="block'+(programsNumber++)+'" class="pgmFirstRow div_'+i+'_2 row2"></div>' +
             '<div id="block'+(programsNumber++)+'" class="pgmFirstRow div_'+i+'_3 row3"></div>' +
        '</div>' +
     '</div><div class="clear"></div>');
  }
  $(".div_"+current_col+'_'+current_row).addClass( "yellowbg" );
}

function getlinks($link,j)
{
  var widthval =  850;
  var parts = $link.split("/");
  var links = parts[parts.length-1];
  var programlength = 0;

  $.ajax({
  url:$.trim(links),
  type:'GET',
  data:'',
  success: function(data)
  {
    var $data = $(data);        
    var title1 = $data.filter("#title1").html();

    var currenttotal = 0;   
    var firstele = ((j-1)*0)+0; // how many blocks i want to output in per block
    var lastele = parseInt(firstele)+0; // how many blocks i want to output AFTER the first block
    var k = 1;
    var programlength = 0;

    for(;firstele <= lastele;firstele++)
    {
      currenttotal++;
      pgmcontent[firstele] = eval('title'+k);
      k++;      
    }
    checksum+=j;

    if(checksuminit == checksum)
    {  
      for(var kk=1;kk <= imagecontent.length-1;kk++)
      {
        $('#image'+kk).html(imagecontent[kk]);
      }
      $("div").show();  
    }
  }   
  });
}
```

In this case, when I press on the down arrow button of the keyboard until I can get on the block 6 and press on the enter button, it supposed to be display "Block 6" on the alert message, but I got the alert message that display with the empty object which it said "[object Object]". I tried to figure out how to extract the text data on each block to display on the alert message when I press enter button.

Here's a sample of what the HTML is look like:

```
<div class="mainWrap">
<div class="row" id="row1"><div id="image1" class="blocksList div_1_1 yellowbg">Block 1</div>
<div class="rowSubPgm"><div id="block1" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_2 row2"></div>
<div id="block2" class="pgmFirstRow div_1_3 row3"></div></div></div><div class="clear></div>
<div class="row" id="row2"><div id="image2" class="blocksList div_2_1">Block 2</div>
<div class="rowSubPgm"><div id="block3" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_2 row2"></div>
<div id="block4" class="pgmFirstRow div_2_3 row3"></div></div></div><div class="clear"></div>
<div class="row" id="row3"><div id="image3" class="blocksList div_3_1">Block 3</div>
<div class="rowSubPgm"><div id="block5" class="pgmFirstRow div_3_2 row2"></div>
<div id="block6" class="pgmFirstRow div_3_3 row3"></div></div></div><div class="clear"></div>
<div class="row" id="row4"><div id="image4" class="blocksList div_4_1">Block 4</div>
<div class="rowSubPgm"><div id="block7" class="pgmFirstRow div_4_2 row2"></div>
```

Here is the fiddle if you need to take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/VZWNE/21/

When I get the alert message to work by display the Block 6, could you please tell me how I can search for the element in another php page until I can find the match element to extract the href link?

E.G when I press down button until when I'm on the block 6, it will search for the class with the element to extract the block 6 text and search for the element on another PHP source to find the match of block 6 then find the href link to extract it which it will display "http://www.hereisthelink.com/test.asx". How I can do that?

here's the HTML source:

```
<p id='blocks'>Block 1<p id='links'>http://www.testsite.com.com/myscript.php?blocks=Block 1</p><a href="">Link 1</a>
<p id='blocks'>Block 2<p id='links'>http://www.testsite.com.com/myscript.php?blocks=Block 2</p><a href="">Link 1</a>
<p id='blocks'>Block 3<p id='links'>http://www.testsite.com.com/myscript.php?blocks=Block 3</p><a href="">Link 1</a>
<p id='blocks'>Block 4<p id='links'>http://www.testsite.com.com/myscript.php?blocks=Block 4</p><a href="">Link 1</a>
<p id='blocks'>Block 5<p id='links'>http://www.testsite.com.com/myscript.php?blocks=Block 5</p><a href="">Link 1</a>
<p id='blocks'>Block 6<p id='links'>http://www.testsite.com.com/myscript.php?blocks=Block 6</p><a href="http://www.hereisthelink.com/test.asx">Link 1</a>
<p id='blocks'>Block 7<p id='links'>http://www.testsite.com.com/myscript.php?blocks=Block 7</p><a href="">Link 1</a>
```

Here's the PHP source to search for the element:

```
<?php

function db_connect()
{
  define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
  define('DB_USER', 'myusername');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
  define('DB_DATABASE', 'mydbname');

  $errmsg_arr = array();
  $errflag = false;
  $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

  if(!$link) 
  {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
  if(!$db) 
  {
    die("Unable to select database");
  }
}

function clean($var)
  {
    return mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($var));
  } 
  $blocks = clean($_GET['blocks']);

  if($errflag) 
  {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    echo implode('<br />',$errmsg_arr);
  }
  else 
  {
  $insert = array();

  if(isset($_GET['blocks'])) 
  {
    $insert[] = 'blocks = \'' . clean($_GET['blocks']) .'\'';
  }
  mysql_close();


  if(!$blocks) 
  {
    $qrytable1="SELECT id, blocks, links FROM mydb_info";
    $result1=mysql_query($qrytable1) or die('Error:<br />' . $qry . '<br />' . mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
    {
      echo "<p id='blocks'>";
      echo $row['blocks'];
      echo '<a href="' . $row['links'] . '">Link 1</a>';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: writing id='links' multiple times in different elements makes the browser very mad and incompliant

Comment: well that's for each element that I need, but how I can extract the text on each block then to find the match element to extract the link below the block, e.g: block 6?

Comment: no - I said it kind of joking around, what I meant is - DO NOT have multiple elements with the exact same id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now the way that I would handle getting the url would be a different much faster approach.  If  you know that from your HTML file say Block 6 is supposed to match "http://www.hereisthelink.com/test.asx" I would simply do something like this.

```
  <div id="image6" class="blocksList div_6_1" 
      data-url="http://www.hereisthelink.com/test.asx">Block 6</div>
```

I think this is a start - the box that is selected will have the class "yellowbg" , here I am extracting the text from that box and putting it in the alert.

```
 if (event.keyCode == 13)
  {  
    alert("enter tested");
    var textFromBlock = $('.yellowbg').html();
    var urlFromBlock = $('.yellowbg').attr('data-url');
    alert("text from box I selected: " + textFromBlock);
    alert("url I wanted: " + urlFromBlock);
  }
```

If this is an option, do it.  The reason is jQuery is searching the entire dom to find where .yellowbg is.  Then you are going to make it search the entire DOM for the text "Block 6" , then make it find the next  tag, then read the HTML from that??  That's a lot of extra work your doing for no reason.  Just put the url that is supposed to belong with Block 6 in a special attribute right there in Block 6 and you can read it.

If you absolutely have to go and find the

that has block 6 , then do this.

```
   <p id='Block 6'>Block 6</p><p id='links'>http://www.testsite.com.com/myscript.php?blocks=Block 6</p><a href="http://www.hereisthelink.com/test.asx">Link 1</a>
```

you were missing a closing `</p>` and you had a bunch with the same id, Change the ID's to match Block 1, 2, 3, 4, ect.

```
 if (event.keyCode == 13)
  {  
    alert("enter tested");
    var textFromBlock = $('.yellowbg').html();
    var urlFromBlock = $("p[id='" + textFromBlock + "']").next('a').attr("href");
    alert("text from box I selected: " + textFromBlock);
    alert("url I wanted: " + urlFromBlock);
  }
```

Comment: You didn't get this right which it didn't make much sense. What I just said, when I press on the enter button of the keyboard, i want to find the two same elements what text is on the block that I already posted the fiddle link in my first post. I want to search the same elements to compare from between the html source to another html source then alert with the link that I extract from a different page. You haven't read my post correctly what I asked for. Please read it again!

Comment: @ChrisJohnson - edited answer , see if that helps .  Please try to re-read your question as well.  It is very broken english and pretty hard to follow.  Especially the first paragraph.  Also please try to take out irrevellant code, that may be why I'm the only one that answered this question.

Comment: thanks for your help. I got the alert when I press on the enter button, but extract the url from the other php is not working. I tried this: var urlFromBlock = $("p[id='" + textFromBlock + "']").next('a').attr("myscript.php"); it said on the alert message "url I wanted: undefined". Any idea?